# Problema com BD (chave estrangeira)

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Meu script é o que segue abaixo. Está dando erro de chave estrangeira e não consigo resolver.

```
CREATE DATABASE teste;
USE teste;

CREATE TABLE horario (
id_horario int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
horario time NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE linha (
id_linha int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
codigo varchar(6) NOT NULL,    
empresa varchar(50) NOT NULL,
sentido boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `markers` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`,             
`cidade`) VALUES
(1, 'Bushere', '1344 R. Jose Demetrio Coelho - Centro, Carmo do Cajuru',     
-20.189388, -44.767197, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru'),
(2, 'Ponto Borracharia do MacarrÃ£o', '21 R. SÃ£o Paulo Centro, Carmo do 
Cajuru', -20.189863, -44.767570, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru'),
(5, 'Ponto do Bairro ViÃ³ria', 'Carmo do Cajuru - MG, 35557-000, B', 
-20.195044, -44.749783, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru');

CREATE TABLE localizacao (
id_localizacao int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_onibus int NOT NULL,
id_ponto int NOT NULL,
horario time NOT NULL,
status int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id_ponto) REFERENCES markers (id)
);

CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_nasc` date NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;    

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `nome`, `telefone`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `data_nasc`, `user`, `senha`, `pontos`, `tipo`) VALUES
(1, 'Gabriel Rabelo Camargos', '37 998637969', 'Azaleias 106 - VitÃ³ria', 'Carmo do Cajuru', '2000-07-04', 'omitogabriel', '123', 0, 1),
(2, 'UsuÃ¡rio', '37 998637969', 'Rua 2 n 371', 'Carmo do Cajuru', '2000-07-04', 'user', '123', 10, 0),
(3, 'Administrador', '99999999', 'Rua 2 nÂº 371', 'Carmo do     Cajuru', '2000-07-04', 'adm', '123', 0, 0),
(4, 'Eduardo Sousa', '(37) 98854-9', 'Rua Pedro Martins Machado, 411', 'DivinÃ³polis', '2000-01-15', 'dudu', '123', 0, 0);


CREATE TABLE rota (
id_rota int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_ponto int NOT NULL,
id_linha int NOT NULL,
dia_semana varchar(6),
sentido varchar(255),
FOREIGN KEY(id_ponto) REFERENCES markers (id),
FOREIGN KEY(id_linha) REFERENCES linha (id_linha)
);

CREATE TABLE onibus (
id_onibus int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_horario int NOT NULL,
id_linha int NOT NULL,
numero varchar(6),
FOREIGN KEY(id_horario) REFERENCES horario (id_horario),
FOREIGN KEY(id_linha) REFERENCES linha (id_linha)
);

ALTER TABLE localizacao ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_onibus) REFERENCES onibus (id_onibus)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há alguns pequenos problemas bobos no seu script. A causa do seu problema é que a tabela `markers` está como `MyISAM`. `MyISAM` não tem suporte a chaves estrangeiras, e não recomendo usar `MyISAM` para absolutamente nada. Use `InnoDB` no lugar disso.

Entretanto, há alguns outros probleminhas também:

- Quebrar linha dentro de um string é uma péssima ideia:

  ```
  (2, 'Ponto Borracharia do MacarrÃ£o', '21 R. SÃ£o Paulo Centro, Carmo do 
  Cajuru', -20.189863, -44.767570, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru'),
  ```
- Há problemas de encoding/charset: `MacarrÃ£o`, `SÃ£o Paulo`, `ViÃ³ria`, `VitÃ³ria`, `UsuÃ¡rio`, `nÂº` e `DivinÃ³polis`.
- Para não ter problemas de encoding/charset use sempre `utf8`. Não use `latin1`.

Assim sendo, recomendo colocar `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` no final de todos os seus `CREATE TABLE`s.

Seu código corrigido fica assim:

```
CREATE DATABASE teste;
USE teste;

CREATE TABLE horario (
  id_horario int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  horario time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE linha (
  id_linha int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  codigo varchar(6) NOT NULL,    
  empresa varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  sentido boolean NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `markers` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `cidade`) VALUES
(1, 'Bushere', '1344 R. Jose Demetrio Coelho - Centro, Carmo do Cajuru', -20.189388, -44.767197, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru'),
(2, 'Ponto Borracharia do Macarrão', '21 R. São Paulo Centro, Carmo do Cajuru', -20.189863, -44.767570, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru'),
(5, 'Ponto do Bairro Viária', 'Carmo do Cajuru - MG, 35557-000, B', -20.195044, -44.749783, 'Ponto', 'Carmo do Cajuru');

CREATE TABLE localizacao (
  id_localizacao int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_onibus int NOT NULL,
  id_ponto int NOT NULL,
  horario time NOT NULL,
  status int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_ponto) REFERENCES markers (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_nasc` date NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `nome`, `telefone`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `data_nasc`, `user`, `senha`, `pontos`, `tipo`) VALUES
(1, 'Gabriel Rabelo Camargos', '37 998637969', 'Azaleias 106 - Vitória', 'Carmo do Cajuru', '2000-07-04', 'omitogabriel', '123', 0, 1),
(2, 'Usuário', '37 998637969', 'Rua 2 n 371', 'Carmo do Cajuru', '2000-07-04', 'user', '123', 10, 0),
(3, 'Administrador', '99999999', 'Rua 2 nº 371', 'Carmo do Cajuru', '2000-07-04', 'adm', '123', 0, 0),
(4, 'Eduardo Sousa', '(37) 98854-9', 'Rua Pedro Martins Machado, 411', 'Divinópolis', '2000-01-15', 'dudu', '123', 0, 0);

CREATE TABLE rota (
  id_rota int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_ponto int NOT NULL,
  id_linha int NOT NULL,
  dia_semana varchar(6),
  sentido varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_ponto) REFERENCES markers (id),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_linha) REFERENCES linha (id_linha)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE onibus (
  id_onibus int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_horario int NOT NULL,
  id_linha int NOT NULL,
  numero varchar(6),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_horario) REFERENCES horario (id_horario),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_linha) REFERENCES linha (id_linha)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE localizacao ADD FOREIGN KEY(id_onibus) REFERENCES onibus (id_onibus);
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no sqlfiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15b566)